# Unary value type

Tags: c#, .net

For some strange reason C# has a binary type 'bool' but seems to lack a similar unary value type.

To work around this I am currently representing unary types as a boolean and having them set to always be false, but of course this opens up the possibility of error later, what if I forget and set one to true? Ideally there would be a value type called the uool which I could declare like so:

```
uool u;
```

I wouldn't need to assign a value to it because it can only have one possible value. I also wouldn't ever need to test it because it's a foregone conclusion what value it holds.

So assuming there isn't such a value type in C# (?) can I make one? Or perhaps there is a suitable workaround that doesn't involve some kind of nasty hack?

Edit: it seems my question goes over some people's heads which is my fault I didn't make it clear so here's a code example that should help:

```
[Serializable]
class CallType
{
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public uool Calls;
    public int NumberOpen {get;}
}
```

Edit: Added Serializable attribute to show use case. Eg:

```
void SendCall(string message, int priority, CallType type)
{
    BinaryStream bs = ....
    //serialize CallType to stream
}
```

Comment: Not really sure about your question, what exactly you are trying to store in a `bool`, it can have `true` or `false` , are you looking for `bool?` which can also have `null` value ? By the way `bool` stands for boolean, not binary ool

Comment: do you need like a bit set?

Comment: *"I wouldn't need to assign a value to it because it can only have one possible value."*  Doesn't sound like a variable to me.

Comment: what other programming languages that you know that have a unary type?

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you want a value type that can only have one possible value. Say `bool` that is _always_ `true` and can _never_ be `false`? Then just declare your own empty value type: `public struct uool {}` EDIT: Not sure on the use-case scenario for this, so I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: you better need a constant :)

Comment: What is the point of having a variable that always is false and will never, ever, change? It's hardly variable

Comment: I didn't say it needed to be a variable

Comment: I agree with the above: @Weyland: are you simply looking for C#'s concept of [`const`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx)? EDIT: Or could you edit your question with a _code sample_ of what you are trying to do? (even if it can't compile, but to better communicate to us what you're trying to achieve)

Comment: what I am after is a simple uoolean

Comment: @WeylandYutani Google shows 364 results for uoolean, hardly any of them make sense... did you just made it up?

Comment: @WeylandYutani: I think a "simple uoolean" is not a common concept. For example, Google says there are only [364 hits for "uoolean"](https://www.google.ca/webhp#nfpr=1&q=uoolean) and far less for "programming uoolean".

Comment: no that's the name i invented for the example, I should have said "unary value type", a value type that can only have one possible value.

Comment: Can you provide an example usage of it?

Comment: @WeylandYutani So .. you've invented a concept, failed to explain a use case, given an example that simply restates your invention, and then said it "goes over people's heads" when nobody can work out your requirement? A simple use case would clarify this massively.

Comment: @WeylandYutani: Regarding your edited code sample, how do you plan to _use_ the `Calls` field? What's the _calling/consuming_ code look like?

Comment: With your last edit, we now know you actually need a constant.

Comment: Im not sure people are really grasping the concept. I've added a new example that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: @WeylandYutani Grasping at straws here, are you trying to find a way to indicate the type of an object once it's been serialised, as you may have other objects with the same base parameters and a *different* unary value type against them?

Comment: i just want an uoolean

Comment: This is a perfectly sensible question that is poorly explained and uses non-standard jargon. FYI this type is usually called "unit" and it is somewhat unfortunate that C# and the CLR lack a standard, built-in unit type. If there were no `void` return type but instead `unit` then there would not have to be a difference between `Func` and `Action` delegates; an `Action` is just a `Func<unit>`, but C# will not allow you to do `Func<void>`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type

Comment: Now, as for the question of why you would ever have a field of unit type, that I don't know. The unit type is usually used as a *return type*, not as a *field type*. As I said, the point of `unit` is that it is a better `void`.  We really need three special return types: `never`, I don't return control at all, `void`, I return no value, and `unit`, I return a predictable value. C# only gives us `void`, which then has to do triple-duty.

Comment: @EricLippert: I understand why you'd want `never`, but why would you need `void` if you had `unit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are asking is not possible.

But you can use constants.

```
const string s = "I'm a constant and I'll not change";
```

But the word variable itself speaks itself. It **varies**

But for your sake how about this:

```
struct Uoolean { }
```

A empty struct? No matter what object you create from it, nothing is gonna change.

Comment: This is not a type unfortunately but good idea

Comment: thanks that's exactly what I want - if you change it to a struct

Comment: You probably want an empty struct, not an empty class.

Comment: @Servy, since I've never used them, I've completely forgot about them.

Comment: Interestingly, there is a scenario where you *would* want to have an empty class, rather than an empty struct.  Specifically, it can be useful to compare empty class types for equality.  For example, Eric Lippert's `Bit` in his [Math from scratch](http://ericlippert.com/2013/09/19/math-from-scratch-part-two/) series.

Answer (score 3):

> I wouldn't need to assign a value to it because it can only have one possible value.

Then it's either a constant or it's superfluous in your code at all.

---

However, regardless how odd a “unary-value type” may sound, you can always use an enum with a single enumeration item only:

```
public enum Useless
{
    TheOnlySemanticallyCorrectValue
}

Useless u = Useless.TheOnlySemanticallyCorrectValue;
```

This construct may be perfectly legal in certain situation. To give an example: imagine a field needs to be declared in a communication protocol or in a fixed-layout data structure, which at the time of original design is allowed to hold just one value. However, in the future the protocol may be extended, and what seemed to be “useless” (and served as a mere placeholder) turns into something very *useful*.

Note: The mere fact that one could legally write `u = 1024;` in C# can be forgotten for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: thanks this looks like what I am after, give me some time to think about it

Comment: Well at least it's extensible — once `Useless` becomes rather *useful*, you can at least declare additional enumeration items. There *are* situations where a type represents a set of just one value, but I consider them rare.

Comment: that's my only worry that someone will define another enum value and break its unaryness

Comment: @WeylandYutani: They can only define a new `enum` value if they have access to change your source code. EDIT: That said, `enums` can have _any_ value assigned to them (as Ondrej pointed out). You could simply define an _empty_ implementation of a `struct` type which should avoid that possibility.

Comment: @WeylandYutani You can always design a unit test that validates it.

Comment: 17 to go for the Reversal badge… Lol! B-)

Comment: 18 for me :) @OndrejTucny

Comment: @AmitJoki Wow, good luck! +1, so 17 only now :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would say a bool would do the job perfectly, with the following convention:

- false: the variable has no value
- true:  the variable has a value

Or you might use the bool? variable, which has a Value parameter or being null when not.

Comment: I upvoted as it does work, but it does require me to suspend belief at using a boolean as a uoolean